# How to handle app URLs in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I recently found that my UIWebView was choking on ITMS links. Specifically, from the UIWebView in my app, if I navigate to a site such as [this one](http://www.oceanobservations.com/thefeed/) and click the "Available on the App Store" link, UIWebView would error out with "Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 The URL can't be shown."

After a bit of Googling, I realized that I needed to catch requests for app links and have iOS handle them. I started out by looking to see if the scheme starts with "itms" in `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, but realized that there might be other kinds of app links that the system can handle. So I came up with this, instead:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)wv didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Give iOS a chance to open it.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSErrorFailingURLStringKey"]];
    if ([error.domain isEqual:@"WebKitErrorDomain"]
        && error.code == 101
        && [[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
        return;
    }

    // Normal error handling…
}
```

I have two questions about this:

1. Is this sane? I'm specifically checking for the error domain and error code and fetching the URL string from the userInfo. Is that stuff likely to remain?
2. This does work for the above-linked app store link, but when I switch back to my app, there appears to have been a subsequent failed request that failed with "Frame load interrupted". how can I get rid of that? It doesn't happen when I have the OS handle the request from `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, so it's a bit annoying.

How do *you* handle such requests?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. In `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`, I ask the OS to handle any non-http and non-https requests that it can, like so:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    // Determine if we want the system to handle it.
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqual:@"https"]) {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This works very well except for the bloody "Frame Load Interrupted" error. I had thought that by returning false from `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` that the web view would not load the request and therefore there would be no errors to handle. But even though I return `NO` above, I still "Frame Load Interrupted" error. Why is that?

Anyway, I'm assuming it can be ignored in `-webView:didFailLoadWithError:`:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)wv didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Ignore NSURLErrorDomain error -999.
    if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) return;

    // Ignore "Fame Load Interrupted" errors. Seen after app store links.
    if (error.code == 102 && [error.domain isEqual:@"WebKitErrorDomain"]) return;

    // Normal error handling…
}
```

And now iTunes URLs work properly, as do `mailto:`s and app links.

Comment: Not just iTunes - I had this with facebook login through web views too.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! But are you sure we can ignore the error 102? Just want to make sure there are side-effects by that. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this answer is linked from the official [**Spotify API** Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/content-linking-guide/)...

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Theory's code, examine the URL for "itms" scheme(s) (this method can be called multiple times due to redirects).  Once you see an "itms" scheme, stop the webView from loading and open the URL with Safari.  My WebView happens to be in a NavigationController, so I pop out of that after opening Safari (less flashing).

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request 
  navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) {
        [webView stopLoading];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: On iOS 6.0 I get scheme as "itmss"

Comment: On iOS 9 the scheme is "itms-appss"

Answer (score -2):

Does it help if you register your app for handling itms: links?

e.g.
http://inchoo.net/iphone-development/launching-application-via-url-scheme/

You may start with scheme `http` but then get an `itms` redirect, which could fail if your app is not registered as handling that scheme.

Comment: I don't want my app to handle the `itms` scheme. I want to know when someone clicks a link in a UIWebView that the view itself can't handle, and then check to see if iOS can handle it, and if it does, have it do so. Nothing to do with whether or not I've registered a URL scheme for my own app.

Comment: There is no way to tell from just looking at the URL. Handling the failure (as you showed) is probably the best way. I suspect "Frame Load Interrupted" might come from a redirect to a itms scheme URL which is why I suggested registering your app as capable.