# Remote image doesn't get displayed in html page displayed in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

The following code

```
<a href="http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewAlbum?i=156093464&id=156093462&s=143441">
<img height="15" width="61" alt="Randy Newman - Toy Story
- You&#39;ve Got a Friend In Me" src="http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/images/
badgeitunes61x15dark.gif"></img>
</a>
```

Is from apple's documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/iTunesLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007896-SW1

When a html page containing that href is loaded into a browser the image is displayed, however when its loaded into a UIWebView it isn't displayed.

ShouldStartLoadWithRequest: does not get called for the following URL

```
http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/images/
badgeitunes61x15dark.gif
```

Why does it not get called and why does this work in a browser but not in UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just built a prototype with your HTML, and it worked fine for me.

However, a few thoughts:

- First, if you implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in your web view delegate, don't expect a callback for every single item in your HTML page.  If I remember correctly, it only calls that for top level requests (e.g. the whole page).  So, I would not expect to get a callback just for that one `img` resource.
- Since we already established that implementing `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` won't do what you want, you might want to remove it altogether.  When I first lazily put it in my code, I forgot to `return YES;` from that method.  Since Objective-C is a rather loose language, the app built and ran, but obviously took `NO` to be the implicit return value from that method.  `NO` stops the request from loading.  If the image was the only thing in a sample page you had, you wouldn't see anything (and maybe falsely think it was just because of the img itself).
- I can't tell if this is only in the HTML that you posted in your question, or if it's in the real code, too.  But, you have whitespace inside your `img src` URL, after `"images/"`.  That would obviously make this break.
- In my test, I also started with a web page that didn't scale content to fit.  That image is rather small, so if you don't scale your web view to fit, and view it on an iPhone/iPod, you might not have noticed such a small image.

```objc
    webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Anyway, that's all I can think of.  Like I said, it works for me.  It's not the image itself, or any difference between Mobile Safari, vs. `UIWebView`.

Double check and report back :)