# Image not showing Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have Xamarin PCL project where I need to show some HTML content in webview. In Android app everything working perfect, but in IOS I have problem with display images. Because its not local content I disable ATS for the app.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Some times I run app webview show image but in most cases its not showing, it just show question mark in a blue square like on attached image.

**question mark in a blue square:**

[image]

Comment: could you give the html content?

Comment: It is not because it is not local content, but rather the resources used in the webpage you show come from a insecure resource, i.e. not using HTTPS

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659324/remote-image-doesnt-get-displayed-in-html-page-displayed-in-uiwebview; 
 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90537/webview-does-not-load-css-and-images-on-ios , maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should add as well the key referring to the content of the web views.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads </key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Anyway, I would suggest you include the specific domain you want to exclude from the ATS because unless you have a very good reason for it, Apple will reject your application in the review process.